# React setState opposite boolean in map function not changing state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I created a simple to-do list in ReactJS. It loads components for to-do items stored in a file "*TodoData.js*", data is stored as followed in that file:

```
const todosData = [
    {
        id:1,
        text: "Take out the thrash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id:2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: false
    },
```

App.js uses a TodoItem.js component to render each to-do item with a *map* function. TodoItem.js uses conditional rendering:

```
   if (props.item.completed == true) {
        return (
        <div className="todoclassDone">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            onChange={ () => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}/>
            <p className="lalatext"><del>{props.item.text}</del></p>
        </div>   
        )
    }
    else { .... //same code as above but with other className.
```

Within App.js I use the TodoItem.js component to render each item in TodoData with a map function; if the data.completed = true background is green, else background is red.

**Problem**: However, the *handleChange(id)* function in App.js is not working properly. I loop through all objects in todosData; if the id is similar to the id of checkbox which the user clicked it should change to the opposite boolean value using *todo.completed = !todo.completed* However, when running this code nothing is happening. *The handleChange function:*

```
  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id == id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
          }
          return todo
      })
```

**Extra info**: Above mentioned problem is especially weird because if I change the boolean value of the checkbox clicked by the user to either false or true it does work. This does not result in the desired behaviour because now I am only able to change the todo.completed once from false to true. ; In this case the *handleChange* function would look as follows:

```
  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id == id) {
          todo.completed = true;
          }
          return todo
      })
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could try to copy state on an array, modify array and set the state wht updated array. Something like:

```
handleChange(id) {
    let result = this.state.todos;
    result = result.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        return todo;
    })
    this.setState({todos: result})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the new state in your `setState` callback, with the new state object.

Example todo component with relevant code:

```
class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: todosData,
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const todos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed
          }
        }

        return todo;
      });

      return { todos };

  }
}
```